# Flexible array member not at end of ‘class - except it is? C++

Tags: c++

I have a class declaration in my header file where at the end I put

```
         Command* commandList[];
```

There is nothing written after that in the class declaration. However, I am getting this error. Why is that?

Here is the class:

```
18 class CommandProcessor {
 19     protected:
 20         vector<string> readCommand();
 21         void saveCommand(vector<string> commands);
 22     public:
 23         int commandCount;
 24         CommandProcessor();
 25         CommandProcessor(const CommandProcessor& game);
 26         ~CommandProcessor();
 27         string state;
 28         string getState();
 29         void setState(string state);
 30         bool validate(vector<string> commands);
 31         string currentCommand();
 32         void consolePlay();
 33         Command* commandList[];
```

Comment: Do you inherit from this class or have one as a member in another class by any chance?

Comment: Care to show more code? Like, maybe, the entire class in question?

Comment: You haven’t shown us your actual code. Are you expecting people to guess?

Comment: @FatihBAKIR Yes, it's in a base class which has two derived classes.

Answer (score 1):

Flexible array members do not exist in C++. If you enable proper standard-conformance in the compiler e.g. with `-pedantic-errors` for GCC and Clang or `/permissive-` for MSVC, they will cause a compilation error in any case. Data members of a class must always have a complete type.

Flexible array members are a C99 feature only available in C. Compilers may allow them in C++ code as a language extension, but only with restrictions.

One of these restrictions is going to be that a class with a flexible array member may not be inherited from. Inheritance with a flexible array member wouldn't work since the derived classes could add members after the flexible array member.